# Copy entries from one MySQL table to another if it does not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to copy entries from one table to another if the entries do not exist. The code below does not make any entries. I can't seem to pin it down. What am I missing here?

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "Pass123", "DB");
$copy="SELECT * FROM TIME";
$doit=$conn->query($copy);
while($row = $doit->fetch_assoc()){
  $check=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM TIME2 WHERE O_LOG='{$row['LOG']}'");
  if(!$check){
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO TIME2 (O_LOG, T_IN, T_OUT, EMP, ITEM, NOTE) VALUES ('".$row['LOG']."', '".$row['T_IN']."', '".$row['T_OUT']."', '".$row['EMP']."', '".$row['ITEM']."', '".$row['NOTE']."')");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: *"What am I missing here?"* - error checking http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: 1) Check the return value of `mysqli_query` to see if it was even successful and 2) Don't forget to commit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- aren't you supposed to use the OO form instead?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot `mysql` is deprecated, not the procedural form of `mysqli`.

Comment: @barmar I tag you because I know your knowledgeable.  Isn't time a mysql reserved word?

Comment: @DarylGill It's a keyword, but not reserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!$check)
```

should be

```
if ($check->num_rows == 0)
```

You're just testing whether the query got an error, not whether it returned no rows.

But instead, you can do it all with one query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TIME2 (O_LOG, T_IN, T_OUT, EMP, ITEM, NOTE)
SELECT LOG, T_IN, T_OUT, EMP, ITEM, NOTE
FROM TIME
```

The `IGNORE` modifier tells it to silently skip any inserts that would cause a duplicate key error (I assume `LOG` is a unique key).

If `LOG` isn't a unique key, you can still do it with one query:

```
INSERT INTO TIME2 (O_LOG, T_IN, T_OUT, EMP, ITEM, NOTE)
SELECT t.LOG, t.T_IN, t.T_OUT, t.EMP, t.ITEM, t.NOTE
FROM TIME AS t
LEFT JOIN TIME2 AS t2 ON t.LOG = t2.O_LOG
WHERE t2.O_LOG IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try below SQL statement which will automatically compare and insert any missing entries to clone table:

```
INSERT INTO `TIME2`
SELECT * FROM `TIME` o
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TIME2` c WHERE c.`O_LOG` = o.`LOG`
) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TIME2 (select * from TIME where LOG not in(select O_LOG from TIME2 ))
```

or

```
INSERT INTO TIME2 (O_LOG, T_IN, T_OUT, EMP, ITEM, NOTE) (select LOG, T_IN, T_OUT, EMP, ITEM, NOTE  from TIME where LOG not in(select O_LOG from TIME2 ))
```